# Disable file logging in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging

the spring-boot application automatically creates spring.log file under temp folder of user_path/AppData/Local/Temp/spring.log

I have a use case where I don't want any of my logs to be written in to log file, whereas I need them to be printed in console output.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove [logging properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.18.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output)

> If you want to write log files in addition to the console output, you need to set a `logging.file` or `logging.path` property (for example, in your `application.properties`).

`logging.path`:

> Writes spring.log to the specified directory. Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.

`logging.file`:

> Writes to the specified log file. Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.

Comment: I want the logs to be displayed in the console. But I don't want any log to be written in the file. In short, there should be no log file generated.

Comment: @ketanpokar you need to find your temp folder definition and remove it